# How to create a Python C extension without using distutils?

Tags: python, cuda

I'm trying to create a Python extension that is written in CUDA C. I don't think distutils supports using the nvcc compiler, so I'd like to learn how a Python C extension can be created without using distutils, and adapt that method to build an extension written in CUDA C.

I'm using Windows and when using distutils I see that building an extension produces .exp, .lib, .obj, and .pyd files. I'm guessing the .exp, .lib, and .obj files are somehow combined into the .pyd file, but don't know how.

Comment: Easiest method: build a library (static or shared) with a flat C API. Then build a Python extension that calls that C API with Cython.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a simple "Hello World"-style example on how to call a C library with Cython that doesn't involve using distutils.

Comment: The extension will be built with distutils. The library will not. Do you know how to build a C library?

Comment: Yes, but I just haven't found a really simple example of calling an external C library with Cython yet.

Comment: Did you look at "interfacing with external C code" in the Cython  documentation? Step one is to obtain .lib and .h files from the "build a C library" procedure. Step two is to use "cdef extern from <header.h>". Step three is to add your .lib file to the "libraries" keyword of the Python extension.

Comment: If instead of a .lib file we have a .dll, do we just put the .dll file in the "libraries" keyword?

Comment: Link always generates a lib when linking a DLL. If you don't have the lib, then you can generate one from the DLL using hacks.

Comment: Personally, I would figure out where the .lib file is located. Which linker are you using?

Comment: I built the DLL using GCC with the "-shared" flag, and it didn't produce a .lib file. Does Cython only work with .lib files, and not DLLs?

Comment: So you are using the mingw ABI, correct? Note that you need to have MSVC installed to build ABI compatible Python extensions. Also note that nvcc uses the MSVC ABI and creates the lib file: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/978822/cuda-setup-and-installation/nvcc-on-windows/post/5027381/#5027381

Comment: I'm using Cygwin. I'm suspecting that DLLs can't be used by Cython because it looks like the "cythonize" method automatically appends ".lib" to the end of the "libraries" parameter.

Comment: Does nvcc even work with cygwin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160866/discussion-between-thomas-and-xaav).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create a Cython extension that used CUDA by following the example found here:

https://github.com/saullocastro/programming/tree/master/cuda/cython/naive_add

Essentially you compile the CUDA code in the command line using nvcc to produce a .lib file. Then just use that .lib file when making the Cython extension as if it were compiled from C. This way distutils can still be used to build the extension, but after the CUDA code has been manually compiled by nvcc.

One small change I had to make was to add the numpy include directory in the command to build the extension. This was the command I used:

```
python setup.py build_ext -i -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -lcudart -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64" --force clean
```